# Calculate difference between dates in the same column but different num?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can't make the request correctly,

The result should show me which number
how long is there a stay in the system.
So when is_loggedin_in_queue = 1 is logged in
when is_loggedin_in_queue = 0 has logged out
the time between 1 and o will show me the total residence time.

below I have shown a request that I have something that does not work properly something small.
Thank you!

```
num        timeofupdate               is_loggedin_in_queue
109     2021-04-27 06:00:02.000       1           
265     2021-04-27 08:32:53.000       1           
265     2021-04-27 11:42:34.000       0           
265     2021-04-27 12:16:28.000       1           
242     2021-04-27 13:23:34.000       0           
242     2021-04-27 14:16:40.000       1           
228     2021-04-27 14:30:25.000       0           
228     2021-04-27 14:30:25.000       0       
228     2021-04-27 15:46:40.000       1           
228     2021-04-27 15:46:40.000       1           
265     2021-04-27 16:41:53.000       0           
242     2021-04-27 16:59:42.000       0           
109     2021-04-27 17:00:00.000       0     


    SELECT *
        FROM [tblAgentQueueStatus] qs2
        WHERE qs2.[timeofupdate] = '2021-04-27' 
        ) qs

        LEFT JOIN [tblAgentQueueStatus] qs1 ON qs.q_num = qs1.q_num 
        AND qs.ag_num = qs1.ag_num 
        AND qs1.is_loggedin_in_queue = 0
        AND qs.[timeofupdate] < qs1.[timeofupdate]
        WHERE qs.is_loggedin_in_queue = 1 
        GROUP BY qs.q_num, qs.ag_num, qs.[timeofupdate]
        ) t
```

The expected result is the time difference is_loggedin_in_queue 1 and is_loggedin_in_queue 0
on the num.

num 109   10:59:58   -The time was logged for everyone else in the same way

Comment: Edit. you question and show the results you want.  Also tag with the database you are using.  And if "server" is supposed to mean SQL Server, the correct tag is "sql-server".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions for this.  Basically you want to assign all `1`s and the following `0` to a group and then aggregate.  You can do this using a cumulative reverse sum to assign the grouping.

```
select min(timeofupdate), max(timeofupdate),
       datediff(second, min(timeofupdate), max(timeofupdate)) as diff_seconds
from (select aqs.*,
             sum(case when is_loggedin_in_queue = 0 then 1 else 0 end) over (order by timeofupdate) as grp
      from tblAgentQueueStatus aqs
     ) aqs
group by grp;
```

This uses SQL Server syntax for the date/time functions.  The choice of SQL Server is mostly based on the square braces in your code.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the lag function to do solve this problem. keep notice that you have some data on your example that doesn't mach your description.

here is [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/03b59/4) to show you the result

and here is the code:

```
select num,
datediff(minute, timeofupdate, prevTimeofupdate) as timeDifference,
(timeofupdate-prevTimeofupdate) as test
from
(
  select *, 
  lag([timeofupdate]) over (partition by [num] order by [num], [timeofupdate]) as prevTimeofupdate
  from Table1
) t
where is_loggedin_in_queue = 0
```